# HowTo initialise MKMapView with a given user location?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, core-location

My app knows the current user position (CoreLocation.framework). 
As soon as the user opens a new MapView his iPhone starts searching for the current position again.
Is it possible to skip that or to change the first user position for mkMapView?

Edit:

Is it possible to overwrite MKMapView and use an other LocationManager?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have a separate location manager object and assign its value to the mapview (BTW, I'm using '=' below as list prefix to prevent the SO code-formatter from borking).

= In your `UIViewController` maintain two separate properties: one to a `MKMapView` and one to a `CLLocationManager`.

= Create a XIB file with the `MKMapView` and any other window chrome you want. Connect the outlets to the controller propeties. Make sure `MKMapView` does NOT follow user location.

= Have the UIViewController implement the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol--especially the `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` method which will be called whenever a new location value is available. We'll be setting the controller as the delegate for the location manager.

= In the viewController's `loadView` method, load the NIB with the `MKMapView` in it. To give user feedback you may want to put up a `UIActivityIndicatorView` spinner and set it to `startAnimating`. Then you start with:

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10; // or whatever
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

= In `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` check to see if the event was  updated since the last N seconds. Then tell the location manager to stop updating, the spinner to stop animating, and get the lat/long data and assign it to the map view along with a view span and region so it zooms and centers to the right place.

= Now here's the tricky part: the blue marble 'throbber' is a feature of the mapview tracking user location. You'll have to momentarily 'fake it' until the real one kicks in (or just use a separate marker for the current location and maintain its position yourself). Personally I'd go with the blue marble that the user is familiar with.

= To make it so it shows right at startup you will need to create a custom MKAnnotationView with just the blue marble graphic added at the location returned by the location manager. This means taking a snapshot of a Mapview with the location showing, then photoshopping just the blue marble out and using it as the image for a custom annotation view.

= If you want it to actively follow the map, you can enable the userlocation tracking of the mapview and when it gets the actual data, you hide your previously set marker and let the mapview do the updating. The other option is to allow the existing location manager to continue receiving updates every second or so and update the position of the blue marble annotation yourself.

= To let the mapview's own userLocation do the updating add to viewDidLoad:

```
[self.map.userLocation addObserver:self 
forKeyPath:@"location" 
options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) 
context:NULL];
self.map.showsUserLocation = YES; // starts updating user location
```

= Implement `observeValueForKeyPath`. It gets called when the `location` attribute of the mapview's `userlocation` has a value:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
      ofObject:(id)object 
        change:(NSDictionary *)change 
       context:(void *)context 
{
     if ([self.map isUserLocationVisible]) {
         [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
         self.ownBlueMarble.hidden = YES;
     }
     // The current location is in self.map.userLocation.coordinate
}
```

= To avoid the warm-up delay in showing current location, keep a reference to the viewController containing the map and the location manager so it doesn't go away (it's a bit of a memory hog but if you release it you'll have to wait again until MapView loads the tiles and is ready to go).

= In `viewWillLoad` you can stuff the last known location into the custom bluemarble annotation and show it. Toggle on/off the userLocation tracking and when you get the notification the same hide-the-annotation-show-the-real-marble trick will work. The mapview's own location manager kicks in and when it has the data, you can make your annotation marker disappear.

= You might want to implement the viewController's `viewWillDisappear` method and manually turn off `userLocation` tracking on the mapview so it's off by default the next time the view is brought up. You'll also want to get the last known `userLocation` and save it for the next get-go. That way, you can do all the positioning marker-juggling in the `viewWillAppear` method and not have to worry about userLocation interfering until you're ready for it.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Ramin. This is not the expected solution however I guess it is the closest existing one.

Comment: Yes, it would have been so much easier if they allowed us to set userLocation on a mapview to an initial value... or better still allow use of an existing CLLocationManager instance instead of creating their own... but unfortunately they don't.

Answer (score 27):

In your controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {latitude: 37.423617, longitude: -122.220154};
    MKCoordinateSpan span = {latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1};
    MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};
    [mapView setRegion:region];
}
```

When map appears it's going to be centered close to Palo Alto

Comment: that is not what I need. I want to change the position of the blue position indicator ("current location").

Comment: userLocation is readonly property, I doubt you can do something about it. The only legal way would be to disable blue indicator that Apple provides and write your own, which is kind of pointless

Comment: Set a 500m x 500 m region      [mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(54.233498f, 1.99375f), 500, 500)];

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `showUserLocation` property to false on initialisation and then restore the `region` the map view previously had (you will obviously have to store this before the previous map is destroyed).

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: no it is not about the region but about the position indicator

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use another Location Manager, you can add whatever points you want to the map and update them via whatever other logic you want.

Let's say you had a socket connection to a remote control car, and that car send back socket data containing geo-location information in the payload.  You could parse that out, and update the location of the thumbnail on your map in real time.  The "userLocation" property is not needed for that, but you could show it if you wanted to.

The location of the user is read-only, you can use it or not.  That doesn't mean you need another location manager to do anything you might need to do.  It sounds like your app doesn't really need that feature, but I could be misunderstanding your question.

Comment: The thing is that the user position is not shown or it is shown wrong for the first 10 seconds a new MKMapView is shown. After these 10 seconds everything is fine. However as I know the position I would love to skip those 10 seconds.

Comment: maybe old, but if someone reads this, you should get the user location when starting the app, which will start the GPS to locate the user. That way by the time the user opens the map, he/she has been located already. pS: it's pretty normal for 10 seconds, even the google maps app takes a few seconds after you turn on location