# Latitude, Longtitude from mapView.userLocation

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, cllocation

I have the following code to get the userLocation on my app:

```
mapView.showsUserLocation=TRUE;
    mapView.userLocation.title=@"Aktuelle Position";
```

That is in the `viewDidLoad();`

But how can I get latitude and longtitude in from `userLocation` in the following method?

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

    Koordinate *user = mapView.userLocation;
    Koordinate *cord1 = [eventPoints objectAtIndex:2];
    CLLocation *loc1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:cord1.latitude longitude:cord1.longtitude];

    Koordinate *cord2 = [eventPoints objectAtIndex:3];
    CLLocation *loc2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:cord2.latitude longitude:cord2.longtitude];

    double distance = [loc1 getDistanceFrom:loc2] / 1000;

    NSLog(@"Distanz:", distance);
}
```

Comment: Here is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449486/iphone-current-user-location-coordinates-showing-as-0-0).

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
  didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
      fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    float lat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude; 
    float lon = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's what worked for me.

```
yourMapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude;
yourMapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude;
```