# Get latitude and longitude from CLLocation

Tags: objective-c, cllocation

I have an CLLocation which is my userLocation,
now in another class I have to open the maps app and make a route from the userLocation to
another point.
But how can I get in the another class the Coordinates of userLocation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Latitude, Longtitude from mapView.userLocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325076/latitude-longtitude-from-mapview-userlocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna need to pass the CLLocation co-ordinates to another class then u can take help of NSUserDefaults

i.e. [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setObject: forKey:@""]

Comment: You can also take shared object like, variable of Location in other class and pass CLLocation co-ordinates.