# How to mark position of iPhone on Google Map?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, gps

I want to make a webpage with a Google Map that marks the geographical position of my iPhone, how do I go about this?

I've looked into the [Google Map API section on markers](http://code.google.com/intl/en-Us/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#Markers) - so I can make a static marker, but I don't know how to pull the GPS data from my iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is here: [iPhone current user location coordinates showing as (0,0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449486/iphone-current-user-location-coordinates-showing-as-0-0)