# Get current location using CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cllocationmanager

I am trying to get current location of user using CLLocationCoordinate2D. I want the values in the format like

CLLocationCoordinate2D start = {-28.078694,153.382844 };

So that I can use them like following:

```
 NSString *urlAddress = [NSString 
       stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f",  
       start.latitude, start.longitude, 
       destination.latitude, destination.longitude];
```

I used

```
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc]init ];
CLLocationDegrees currentLatitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
CLLocationDegrees currentLongitude = location.coordinate.longitude;
```

to get current lat & long.

But I am getting 0.000 for both when I try to test. I am testing on iPhone 4s.

If there is any sample code, it will be great.

Comment: Are you using an `MKMapView`?

Comment: How are you getting your coordinates? Add the code of what you've tried so far.

Comment: I am using  CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc]init ];
    CLLocationDegrees currentLatitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
   
    CLLocationDegrees currentLongitude = location.coordinate.longitude;

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add CoreLocation framework first and then use the following code...and your viewController  must implement CLLocationManagerDelegate

```
-(void)findCurrentLocation
{

    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    if ([locationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        locationManager.delegate = self; 
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; 
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }


    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" latitude:%f longitude:%f",coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);


}
```

Comment: `[locationManager location]` in this example may return `nil` or very old location. The best way to get current location is to wait while `locationManager` will send callback message to its delegate. But still location passed with callback message may be old, thus, you need always to check timestamp of location.

Comment: Its not working for me latitude and longitude values coming like this 0.00000

Answer (score 7):

in AppDelegate.h declare following variable. and implement

```
CLLocationManagerDelegate delegate.

CLLocationManager *locationManager;
CLLocation *currentLocation;
```

in AppDelegate.h.m file write following code.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {       

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    self.currentLocation = newLocation;
    self.currentLat =  newLocation.coordinate.latitude; 
    self.currentLong =  newLocation.coordinate.longitude; 
}
```

Comment: self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; the leak is there in the line.

Answer (score 2):

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [[[mapview userLocation] location] coordinate];  
NSLog(@"Location found from Map: %f %f",location.latitude,location.longitude);
```

and also refer the link(without mapview0

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I am not using mapview, just adding start and destination to google maps. And then displaying them in UIWebView. How can I get it without mapview?

Comment: Yes, you can go without `MKMapView`. It is little bit to hard to understand, why you use `UIWebView`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449486/iphone-current-user-location-coordinates-showing-as-0-0

Comment: Although this query has been solved, I would like to know how can I invoke actual directions page instead of page that has start and end locations added with google maps?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `CLLocationManager` to get a user's location. `CLLocation` is only a class of objects used to represent locations, it can't get user location by it self.

For more details and example, please follow to Apple docs on [Location Awareness Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html).

Comment: Please, check out Apple docs on [Location Awareness Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html).

Answer (score 1):

use location manager to get lat and long, follow this tutorial for sample code http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/miscellaneous/how-to-get-current-latitude-and-longitude-in-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)findCurrentLocation
{
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    [self setLocation:[[manager location] coordinate]];
}
```