# iPhone: Application Testing and Core Location

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, unit-testing, ocunit

I'm trying to implement Application Tests as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html). So far, so good, but i fail to test, for instance, the location of the device using Core Location. I have added the appropriate Framework to the Target, and have initiated the update of location, but i have no clue of how to wait for the location to be loaded, the test suite just ends before the second thread finish. Please help me to find a way to test this sort of things.

Comment: Good luck with this one. I couldn't get that to work... :-)

Comment: This is also what I am looking for with my unit testing. It looks like the application-tests are started before applicationDidFinishLaunching gets called.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar, and hoping to mock the location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're relying on `CLLocationManager` you can implement these two delegate methods in `CLLocationManagerDelegate`:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Then you set the `CLLocationmanager` delegate and tell it to `startUpdatingLocation`. If you get  `didUpdateLocation` (with `oldLocation` set to nil) it means you now have a location and you can consider the test a success (make sure you turn off updating). If you get the other one there was a location-manager error.

If you're relying on MapKit and are using `MKMapView`'s user-location update mechanism, then take a look at my response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437568/howto-initialise-mkmapview-with-a-given-user-location/1495998#1495998) and implement the observer section (`observeValueForKeyPath`) to be notified when the map has a location (success) or implement MKMapViewDelegate's `mapViewDidFailLoadingMap` to be notified if there was an error.

Comment: Ramin, sorry, it seems that i was not able to explain myself. My issue is not how to get the location in the real app, but how to test the application. Let me try again: 
Let's say, for instance, that i trigger the startUpdatingLocation on applicationDidFinishLaunching: and set the appDelegate as the delegate of the CLLocationManager. The question is how to set the test suite to be able to test whether the CLLocationManager delegate receives locationManager:didUpdateLocation:fromLocation: As far as i was able to get, the test just ends before the delegate calls are triggered. 
Anythow, thanks