# Change user's current location manually in MKMapView Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mkmapview

In the starting, I am displaying my current location. But after that, I want to update my current location on the basis of lat-long I get from the API.

How can I update the current location based on the lat long?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437568/howto-initialise-mkmapview-with-a-given-user-location

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot do it because `mapView.userLocation` is a get-only property.

e.g.

```
mapView.userLocation.location = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude,
                                           longitude: coordinate.longitude)
```

cause error

> Cannot assign to property: 'location' is a get-only property